# Background image won't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change div's background image inside setInvterval, but can't figure out how. Here's the code:

```
$('.thumbnail').on({
        'mouseenter': function(){
            var thumbs = $(this).attr('data-num-thumbs');
            var thumb_url = $(this).css('background-image');
            console.log(thumb_url);
            var i = 1;
            setInterval(function(){
                var new_thumb_url = thumb_url.replace(/\d{1,2}\.jpg/gi, i + '.jpg');
                console.log(new_thumb_url);
                $(this).css('background-image', new_thumb_url);
                i++;
                if(i > 10) i = 1;
            }, 3000);
        });
});
```

This is how `div` looks like:

```
<div data-num-thumbs="17" class="thumbnail" style="background: url('http://site/img/11.jpg') no-repeat;"></div>
```

Comment: It is possible that inside your `setInterval` `$(this)` is something else than you might expect.

Comment: yes, you're right. So how can I pass argument to the setInterval function?

Comment: so whats happening with current code ?

Comment: I suppose you could add another variable `var target` or something, and use that in your `setInterval` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$(this)`  inside `setInterval()` is mapping to something else , try this

```
$('.thumbnail').on({
    'mouseenter': function(){
        $this=$(this);  //store $(this) in a local var
        var thumbs = $(this).attr('data-num-thumbs');
        var thumb_url = $(this).css('background-image');
        console.log(thumb_url);
        var i = 1;
        setInterval(function(){
            var new_thumb_url = thumb_url.replace(/\d{1,2}\.jpg/gi, i + '.jpg');
            console.log(new_thumb_url);
            //$(this).css('background-image', new_thumb_url);
            $this.css('background-image', new_thumb_url);
            i++;
            if(i > 10) i = 1;
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Happy Coding:)

Comment: @putvande: thanks for that bro, i didnt notice that.